# php pass value to another php using sql

Tags: php, html, sql, if-statement

Here I am trying to build a dropdown list with a submit, using post, to get to another php which will use sql to display a list depending on which option is selected in the dropdown list. Anyway, here's the code

```
<?Php

echo "<!DOCTYPE html><html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>Homework answers</title>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body  align=center>";

echo "<p align='center'><b>Q6: </b>Display a drop-down menu which contains  the projectID and project name of all the project(s).</p><br><br>";
echo "<p align='center'>projectIDs and names:";

echo "<form name='form' action='q6.php' method='post'>";
echo "<select>";
echo "<option value='1'>1:Programming Contest</option>";
echo "<option value='2'>2:New Year Dinner</option>";
echo "<option value='3'>3:SSkill Transfer Project</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</p>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

q6.php:

trying to do something like this:

```
$var_value = $_POST['value'];
if ($var_value='1'){
$query = "SELECT taskID, name, startDate, endDate From Task WHERE projectID='1' ORDER BY taskID;";
}

elseif ($var_value='2'){
$query = "SELECT taskID, name, startDate, endDate From Task WHERE  projectID='2' ORDER BY taskID;";
}

elseif ($var_value='3'){
$query = "SELECT taskID, name, startDate, endDate From Task WHERE projectID='3' ORDER BY taskID;";
}
```

Hope everyone gets my idea...and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You are doing an assignment instead of comparing the values, if($foo=bar)

Comment: hi, sorry my question is how to make the $query of q6.php be different depending on the choice of the value from the drop down list from the previous php file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**q6.php**

You are doing an assignment instead of comparing the values

**change this**

```
  if($var_value ="1")
```

**to**

```
    if($var_value =="1")
```

**=** is an assignment operator 
== is a comparision operator

```
  $var_value=$_POST["value"];
 if($var_value =="1")
  {//do something}

 elseif($var_value =="2")
  {//do something}
```

**your html form**

> Don't omit the name attribute, otherwise your form data will not be submitted to the server.

add the name attribute to your select element

```
   <select name="value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You need to give your select some name:

```
echo "<select name = 'select_name'>";
echo "<option value='1'>1:Programming Contest</option>";
echo "<option value='2'>2:New Year Dinner</option>";
echo "<option value='3'>3:SSkill Transfer Project</option>";
echo "</select>";
```

Then you can reference it in your php file like this, without if statements:

```
if(isset($_POST['select_name']){
    $var_value = $_POST['select_name'];
    $var_value= mysql_real_escape_string($var_value);
    $query = "SELECT taskID, name, startDate, endDate From Task WHERE projectID='$var_value' ORDER BY taskID;";

}
```